# ERROR: Could not build wheels for hdbscan, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

Tags: python, hdbscan

While trying to install hdbscan with pip I get this error.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
ERROR: Failed building wheel for hdbscan
Failed to build hdbscan
ERROR: Could not build wheels for hdbscan, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

Do you have any suggestions how I can fix this? I'm pretty new to python.

I also tried conda install hdbscan but then this error occures:

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

- hdbscan

Current channels:

- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

```
https://anaconda.org
```

and use the search bar at the top of the page.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the python-dev package for the version of python you are using.

So on Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-dev
```

or, for example:

```
sudo apt-get install python3.10-dev
```